# Kleopatra won't open

Tags: gnupg, pgp, decryption, openpgp, kleopatra

Out of the blue Kleopatha just refuses to open, I have dug through the internet and found nothing that works. I ran it as an admin and for some reason it shows in task manager that its there but nothing pops up for me at all as if I never even opened it.

Unfortunately I had backed up the wrong private key, but of course I have the public key. So im thinking the only way i will be able to make this work is if i magically get Kleopatra to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: I had a simillar problem some years ago, but ultimately I found that there was some network traffic filtering on my organizations network. I ended up just going down to a coffee shop, and it worked from there. probably not the same issue, but figured I'd share.

Comment: What do logs say, or the system Event Viewer? What does the private and public keys have to do with this issue?